# Split data after sampling

Tags: r, split, sample

```
data(kyphosis)
ky<- kyphosis
```

By this I made a data set consisting of 40% of original one.

```
ky_40 <- ky[sample(1:nrow(ky), nrow(ky)*0.4,replace=FALSE),]
```

By this statement I want to make a data set consisting of 60% of the original one excluding

```
ky_40.
ky_the_others<- ???????
```

How can I make the last code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just move the sampling out of your extraction so you can refer to it again:

```
ky <- mtcars

## Here, I've moved the sampling out of your extraction
forty <- sample(1:nrow(ky), nrow(ky)*0.4,replace=FALSE)

## Now you can extract whatever you want
ky[ forty, ]    # This will be the 40% of original dataset
ky[-forty, ]    # This will be the remaining rows.
```

Answer (score 1):

```
unique(rbind(ky_40,ky))[-(1:nrow(ky_40)),]
```

Comment: sorry but I noticed that my solution sometimes could not work well: the function "unique" could eliminate also rows you would like to keep only because they're equal. Thus, in general words, my solution works with data frames with rows not equal to each other.